# Error: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element Whatsapp

Tags: python, web-scraping

This is my code:

```
def enviar_mensagem(nav):
    #Lê uma planilha do excel. Na coluna 'Concat2' envia o link da célula para o navagedor que envia a mensagem para o número da lista.
     mailing = pd.read_excel('mailing.xlsx') #STEP1)
     for i in range(len(mailing)):
        URL = mailing['Concat2'][i]#STEP3
        print(URL)
        nav.get(URL)
        find_elements_side(nav)
        time.sleep(1)
        entra = nav.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div[4]/div/footer/div[1]/div/span[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]')
        entra.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
        time.sleep(2)#STEP3
        path = "/html/body/div[1]/div/span[2]/div/span/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div"
        #WebDriverWait(nav, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, path))).click()
```

I'm trying to develop a Whatsapp message trigger. I have a xlsx sheets with a list of cell numbers. For each cell number I'll send a predefined message and generate a link to driver get in - for example ("https://web.whatsapp.com/send?phone=551988006472&text=Olá,%20Cris.%20Você%20está%20recebendo%20um%20teste%20de%20automação.%20Obrigado%20pela%20compreensão%20e%20uma%20ótima%20sexta").
The problem that I'm facing is: when the cell number dosen't have a Whatsapp account my code crash and the program stops. So, how can I skip the error (Cell number doesn't have whatsapp account) without stop the program?
The message error that's shows me:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Valor\Documents\Disparador\working.py", line 54, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\Valor\Documents\Disparador\working.py", line 53, in main
    navigation_whatsapp(nav)
  File "C:\Users\Valor\Documents\Disparador\working.py", line 30, in navigation_whatsapp
    enviar_mensagem(nav)
  File "C:\Users\Valor\Documents\Disparador\working.py", line 41, in enviar_mensagem
    entra = nav.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div[4]/div/footer/div[1]/div/span[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]')
  File "C:\Users\Valor\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 1251, in find_element
    return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {
  File "C:\Users\Valor\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 430, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\Valor\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 247, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div[4]/div/footer/div[1]/div/span[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]"}
  (Session info: chrome=102.0.5005.63)
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
    Ordinal0 [0x009AD953+2414931]
    Ordinal0 [0x0093F5E1+1963489]
    Ordinal0 [0x0082C6B8+837304]
    Ordinal0 [0x00859500+1021184]
    Ordinal0 [0x0085979B+1021851]
    Ordinal0 [0x00886502+1205506]
    Ordinal0 [0x008744E4+1131748]
    Ordinal0 [0x00884812+1198098]
    Ordinal0 [0x008742B6+1131190]
    Ordinal0 [0x0084E860+976992]
    Ordinal0 [0x0084F756+980822]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00C1CC62+2510274]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00C0F760+2455744]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00A3EABA+551962]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00A3D916+547446]
    Ordinal0 [0x00945F3B+1990459]
    Ordinal0 [0x0094A898+2009240]
    Ordinal0 [0x0094A985+2009477]
    Ordinal0 [0x00953AD1+2046673]
    BaseThreadInitThunk [0x76706739+25]
    RtlGetFullPathName_UEx [0x77978FEF+1215]
    RtlGetFullPathName_UEx [0x77978FBD+1165]
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow!  Are you familiar with `try` blocks in Python?

Comment: use `id`, `class` or other values to search object. Using long path with `div` may not work if page use JavaScript to adds some elements.

Comment: if you get error then use `try/except` to catch it. Eventually you can use `find_elements()` - with `s` at the end - and you get list with all matching elements. If there is no matching elements then it gives empty list instead of raising error.

Answer (score 0):

In Python, you can intercept raised exceptions when they occur (e.g., for inspection or suppression) with `try`/`except`.

For example,

```py
try:
    print(1/0) # This will raise a ZeroDivisionError.
except ZeroDivisionError: # We specify which class of exceptions we're interested in catching.
    print('I divided by zero.')
```

This runs the code inside of the `try` block and, if an exception of the specified type (in this case, `ZeroDivisionError`) occurs, then, instead of propagating the error and potentially crashing the program, the code inside of the `except` block is run.

In your case, the line

```py
entra = nav.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div[4]/div/footer/div[1]/div/span[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]')
```

is raising a `selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException`.  You could, therefore, intercept such an exception by:

```py
try:
    entra = nav.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div[4]/div/footer/div[1]/div/span[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]')
except selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException:
    # Handle the error somehow.
```

However, this will only catch `NoSuchElementException` exceptions.  If some other selenium type occurs, then the error will propagate and your program will crash.  To solve this, you can look at `NoSuchElementException`'s inheritance hierarchy:

```py
> selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException.__mro__
(selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException,
 selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException,
 Exception,
 BaseException,
 object)
```

So, you could widen your net by

```py
except selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException:
```

You might be tempted to widen it further by catching all `Exception`s.  However, this is, in general, bad practice.  You should be specific as possible about the types of exceptions you'd like to catch.  After all, what if, for example, an exception occurs in your `try` block because of a mistake **you** made (i.e., not one raised by selenium)?  You'd want that exception to crash your program so that you know to fix the mistake.